# Should I use graphQL for requests that don't concern application data, like request to log out from third party services?

Tags: http, graphql, rpc

I am working on a project where we use graphql.

Now I want to create an endpoint in the backend that accepts an id token and logs a user out from third-party services.

Should this endpoint, that has nothing to do with application data, be a graphql endpoint like all our other endpoints or should it rather be HTTP rest/rpc endpoint?

Answer (score 1):

I would recognize logging to (/out from) third-party service at the same level as data - both are resources you're working on as part of your serice.

You can wrap (stitching, delegating) any service(s) you want - one of graphQL advantages is it's ability to hide changes - when sth will change (new 3rd parties) you'll just update your resolver. No app update, no many endpoints management (API versions).